# air for ios application without provision?

Tags: ios, flash, air

Is there a possibility to generate .ipa that could be installed on any iPad/iPhone without checking provison? 
I would like to put my app to server in student's Intranet that anyone could download, and install it.
I was trying Ad hoc deployment, but the provision is checked.
Also replacing ProvisionedDevices array, in provision file, with ProvisionsAllDevices won't help 
I'm member of iOS Developer Program and working with Flash CS6, Air 3.4.

Comment: Just as of curiosity, if you get it working let us know what was the deal.

Comment: unfortunately there is no possible to do it in this way.
The only option (besides described by you) is purchase enterprise license, with is almost the same as developer with max 500 devices, or corporate license (without limit of devices). The problem is, you can publish app legally only for devices registered to you, or your company. If you want to develop for bussines partner, you have do give them soruce code. They should have corporate license to sign app for themself. That's all I get from contact with apple support. This bussines model sounds stupid for me (as client and developer).

Comment: you do not have to give source code to client. all you need is all client devices ids. for sure this is not nice.. and involves a lot of certificates modifications and so on... but you can charge them each time they add a new device on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will never allow an unsigned IPA to run on their device.  So you have to sign it.  You are not allowed to just give the app out to anyone, because Apple needs to review it.

Comment: application is deployed with .p12 certificate, so it's signed. What is the difference if I add device to provision file, and then install aplication, or I will install it rapidly without provision. Apple still don't know anything about my application, only about my devices. What's the point of this philosophy?

Comment: The point is they don't want knuckleheads throwing random crap onto their devices.  They want their users to feel safe that any application they install will not cause harm to their device or personal information.  My answer was a bit short, but the point is that is why they require you to sign it with a profile that is either meant for a limited number of devices (for testing purposes) or meant for the app store (for which it is reviewed by Apple to ensure there is no monkey business)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to distribute apps without apple store is to use ad-hoc distrinbution.
This means (independent from air or obj.c):

1. you need an apple developer certificate (the 299 euro ones)
2. create ad-hoc certificate under apple developer website
3. include all the devices uids that you redistribute (max 100) to ad-hoc cetificate

   - only devices with uid included in the certificate will be able to install app (except jailbroken deviced)
4. build .ipa using p12 and prov. certificate from apple.